# Split list of tuples into different partitions in ML

Tags: list, tuples, ml

I've done Python for quite awhile and what I'm trying to achieve should've been identical but I'm running into a pesky error.

My problem is that I would like a list of tuples in ML split into separate variables.

```
val myList = [(1,2),(3,4)];
val (x :: y) = myList;
```

In the above statement x would be (1,2) and y would be (3,4), ... [If there was anymore]. Simple enough.

Now I want to introduce a third variable z where z would be (3,4),... and x, y would be (1,2) respectfully.

```
val myList = [(1,2),(3,4)];
val ((x :: y) :: z) = myList;
```

The error produced by the previous snippet is:

```
error: Pattern and expression have incompatible types.
Pattern: ((x :: y) :: z) : 'a list list
   Expression: myList : (int * int) list
   Reason: Can't unify 'a list to int * int (Incompatible types)
```

Edit: As requested, this is what z should achieve.

```
val myList = [(1,2),(3,4)];
val ((x :: y) :: z) = myList;
```

Output would be:
x = 1, y = 2, z = (3,4)

In Python this would be:

```
Python 3.9.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 11 2021, 
03:35:11) 
[Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> (x,y),z = [(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> z
(3, 4)
```

Comment: Can you explain more about this `Now I want to introduce a third variable z where z would be (3,4),... and x, y would be (1,2) respectfully.`?

Comment: Sure check for an edit in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, :: doesn't denote a comma where as in Python I would've used one. Switching between the two solves this:

```
val ((x :: y) :: z) = myList;
```

Now becomes:

```
val ((x, y), z) = myList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet doesn't do what you think it does:

```
val myList = [(1, 2), (3, 4)];
val (x :: y) = myList;
```

The pattern `x :: y` binds `x` to the head of the list (in this case, `(1, 2)`), and `y` to the [tail of the list](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/NOTES/node49.html) (in this case, `[(3, 4)]`, not `(3, 4)`). If you want to extract the first two elements, do this:

```
val myList = [(1, 2), (3, 4)];
val x :: y :: z = myList;
```

`x` will be bound to `(1, 2)`, the tail will again be pattern-matched so that `y` is bound to `(3, 4)`, and `z` to the empty list `[]`.

To pattern-match the pieces in a pair (2-tuple), use `(x, y)`. The following should achieve what you want:

```
val myList = [(1, 2), (3, 4)];
val (x, y) :: z :: _ = myList;
(* x: 1
 * y: 2
 * z: (3, 4)
 *)
```